# Disable AFK timer on Terraria server

Tags: terraria

I'm playing on a Terraria server with some friends, (it's a dedicated server hosted on Linux if that helps) and one of my friends has an AFK mob farm, but the problem is Terraria has an AFK timer that kicks you after a while, is there any way to disable that?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. Are you sure this is a vanilla server without any custom functionality?

Comment: Completely vanilla, however, we just put in a minecart loop to combat this, thanks for the help